nftables: Block ARP packets for a range of mac addresses
I want to block ARP packets for a range of Mac addresses including any address whose last octet are from 1 to 10, for example addresses 04:01:01:01:01:01 or 04:01:01:01:01:05 or 06:10:10:10:ff:0a must be dropped (and any address in between).
For a single address I can do this way, but I don't know for a range:
meta protocol arp arp saddr ether 04:11:22:33:44:80 drop

Is it possible to do this with nftables?

Do you mean a range of MAC addresses, or do you mean a list? I'm going to assume the latter (list), based on the description in your question.
You can create sets in your nftables ruleset that hold multiple values, and then use those sets instead of individual values in your matching rules.
For example, to block traffic from a set of MAC addresses:
table inet blocklist {
    # define the set of MAC addresses we want to block
    set block_these_macs {
        typeof ether saddr
            elements = { 04:01:01:01:01:01,
                         04:01:01:01:01:05,
                         06:10:10:10:ff:0a }
    }

    # create a filter chain that will block inbound traffic
    # on eth0 if the source MAC addresses is contained in the
    # block_these_macs set.
    chain block_input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        iif eth0 ether saddr == @block_these_macs counter drop;
    }
}


Sorry for inconvenience, but I mean the first (range). Thanks for your reply.

To drop arp based on a range of last digit you can do something like:
meta protocol arp arp saddr ether & ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa == 00:00:00:00:00:0a drop
Full example by using arp table:
add table arp arp_table

add chain arp arp_table input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
}

# TODO: Drop if last digit is 1-10 (1-A) in hex
add rule arp arp_table input arp saddr ether & ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa == 00:00:00:00:00:0a drop

The only problem is I'm not sure how to mask last digit so that 1-10 (1-A) is matched as range.

Thanks a lot, this is a better solution compared to a range one (it's not what i asked but fixed my problem, it's more like a wildcard solution). Also you need to edit bit-wise section to this & 00:00:00:00:00:0a == 00:00:00:00:00:0a

Glad to hear it's useful, just in case it doesn't work as intended you can play with XOR ^ or some other bitwise operation.
